# Search entire text for images

Tags: string, search

I have a problem with a project.
I need to search a string for images.
I want to get the source of the image and modify the html form of the img tag.
For example the image form is:

and I want to change it to:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<hr class="visible-sm visible-xs tall" />
<a class="img-thumbnail lightbox pull-left" href="upload/uploader/up_164.jpg" data-plugin-options='{"type":"image"}' title="Image title">
<img class="img-responsive" width="215" src="upload/uploader/up_164.jpg"><span class="zoom"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</span></a>
```

I have done some part of this.

I can find the image, change the form of the html but cannot loop this for all images found in the string.

My code goes like

Using the following function I get the string between two strings

```
//  Get substring between
function GetBetween($var1="",$var2="",$pool){
    $temp1 = strpos($pool,$var1)+strlen($var1);
    $result = substr($pool,$temp1,strlen($pool));
    $dd=strpos($result,$var2);
    if($dd == 0){
    $dd = strlen($result);
    }

    return substr($result,0,$dd);
}
```

And then I get the image tag from the string

```
$imageFile = GetBetween("img","/>",$newText);
```

The next was to filter the source of the image:

```
$imageSource = GetBetween('src="','\"',$imageFile);
```

And for the last part I call str_replace to do the job:

```
$newText = str_replace('oldform', 'newform', $newText);
```

The problem is in case there are more tha one images, I cannot loop this process.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best, simple and safe way to read an xml file is to use an xml parser.

And, I think you will gain a lot of time.

Comment: The data are not from xml files but from a database.

Comment: Since your file is construct with tag, it's an XML file. HTML files are a kind of XML files.

Comment: As i wrote before, the data come from a database, not from a file. I am trying to modify the look of an image by applying a new class and style. So  I read the record and every time i see image source I want to modify the result.